# has anyone attended ROS Summer School

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I am thinking of applying for the ROS Summer School 2017 - https://www.fh-aachen.de/fachbereiche/maschinenbau-und-mechatronik/international/ros/

Has anyone here attended the course, is it worth it (to me it looks like it) - any pointers / suggestions / alternatives ???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260712/has-anyone-attended-ros-summer-school/) by [zaidpirwani](https://answers.ros.org/users/27018/zaidpirwani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I haven't but I'm thinking in going this year too, although it is kind of difficult for me because I'm located in the USA. For me, it is worth it for the following reasons:

- Networking
- 500 euros of scholarship
- Hands on a real robot using ROS
- Sort of vacations
- Participation at Urban Challenge Competition
- CV?

Other than that it seems to me that the program is too basic and you can learn that stuff by yourself and for free.

Best,

---

Originally posted by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) with karma: 188 on 2017-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zaidpirwani](https://answers.ros.org/users/27018/zaidpirwani/) on 2017-04-30**:
Thanks - I still hope to hear from someone who has attended the school.